# error "Undefined index" with a form in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code and I have two problem 
the one is this line:

> Notice: Undefined index: elm1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\art-legend\12\edit\index.php on line 65

line 65 in my local is in this page this line 
( $editor = $_POST['elm1'];)

and the other error: when I submitted the code go to no page (Object not found!) and this is the form code in the same page:

```
<form method="post" action="<? echo $PHP_SELF; ?>">

                <div>
                <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
            ....
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <br />
        <input type="submit" value="gooooo" name="submit" />

    </form>
<?

$localhost = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password ="adminpass"; 
$db = "im";

$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost,$user,$password,$db);
$editor = $_POST['elm1'];

$sql = "insert into images(name) values('$editor')";
$query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

$sql2 = "select images.name from images";
$query2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['name'];

    }

?>
```

the line in this code

```
$editor = $_POST['elm1'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$localhost = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password ="adminpass"; 
$db = "im";


$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost,$user,$password,$db);

if(isset($_POST['elm1'])){ //This line
$editor = $_POST['elm1'];
$sql = "insert into images(name) values('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $editor)."')";
$query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
}

$sql2 = "select images.name from images";
$query2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo $row['name'];

}



?>
```

Comment: and please for the love of god sanitize your input or better, use prepared statements.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string() added to the answer..at least it's something xD

Comment: OP should really consider [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Comment: Maybe he is switching from the old mysql_* extension...

Answer (score 0):

First time the page is loaded there will be no post variables. Try wrapping your code inside:

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

 }
```

Also read about [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: yes the one problem is working now , but why when i submited go to Object not found!

Comment: look at the html and make sure that `action=""` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: <form action="<? echo $PHP_SELF ; ?>" method="post">
is this wrong ?

Comment: Look at the html of the rendered page and make sure that everything is coming out right when you load the page.